# Kotlin: Suppress unused Property?

Tags: kotlin, suppress-warnings

My source code is as follows:

There are warnings : Property '****' is never used.

I added "@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")",  "@Suppress("UNUSED_PROPERTY_GETTER")", "@Suppress("UNUSED_PROPERTY_SETTER")",
however, none of them work.

How can I suppress this warning?

[image]

Comment: You could add `data` modifier to avoid warnings

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `@Suppress("unused")` in order to suppress unused warning.

For those cases you can use the IDE. press `alt+enter`:
[image: IDE unused suppress]

Comment: Pressing Alt+Enter on an unused *property* (as in the question) rather than an unused *parameter* (as in this answer), I do not see any option to suppress the warning.

Comment: For me, property works perfectly. The syntax I would never have come up with on my own, without me IDE though:
`@file:Suppress("unused")`

Comment: I am using Android Studio, and it works for me perfectly

Comment: to me there's no option to press Alt + Enter, but I can add it manually and it loses this annoying warning

Comment: odd I don't get that drop down, no safe delete option.  Maybe cause I am on a method and not a class constructor?