# How to suppress specific Kotlinc/Javac compiler warnings?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

How to suppress `deprecations` in for `KotlinCompile` in `Gradle` similar to `JavaCompile`?

**JavaCompile(works):**

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    configure(options) {
        compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-deprecation'
    }
}
```

**KotlinCompile(does not work):**

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjavac-arguments=-Xlint:-deprecation"]
    }
}
```

**References:**

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#compiler-options

**Similar questions:**

- [kotlin supress warning deprecated for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676512/kotlin-supress-warning-deprecated-for-android)
- [Mark unused parameters in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046636/mark-unused-parameters-in-kotlin)
- [Kotlin: Suppress unused Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192281/kotlin-suppress-unused-property/43192848)
- [How do I make the Kotlin compiler treat warnings as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562200/how-do-i-make-the-kotlin-compiler-treat-warnings-as-errors)

Comment: seems like is not possible to achieve it through kotlin compiler arguments, https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/cli/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/CLITool.kt

Comment: try this`tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
            kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ["--Xjavac-arguments=-Xlint:-deprecation"]
        }` here https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/859

Comment: @AkashShah I don't see any reference to this issue in the link you posted.

Comment: There is an open issue for this feature https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8087.
Until it's closed you will have to put `@Suppress("DEPRECATION")` on each call-site of deprecated API.

Answer (score 3):

Currently Kotlin does not support Surpressing compiler warnings. They do have some categories to surpress. But different then that the only way none is:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
```

Sometimes Surpress will not work by just inputing the annotation which should work on runtime. You might need to add something like the following

```
val foo = error.asDynamic().response
if (foo is AxiosResponse<String>) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    val response = foo as AxiosResponse<String>
}
```

Which is not your case. But apparently other people have had the similar issue. I suggest taking a brief look at reddit. Which also not the case above but can lead you.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/bsgk5w/what_do_i_have_to_do_to_suppress_my_unchecked/

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to suppress deprecations, so you can make the build fail on each other Kotlin warnings, then this is my experience.

There is a way to configure the Kotlin compiler to make it fail on each warning. Just add the following configuration to your `build.gradle` file:

```
// For Android Project
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        allWarningsAsErrors = true
    }
}
// For non Android Project
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        allWarningsAsErrors = true
    }
}
```

But after enabling the `allWarningsAsErrors` flag, the Kotlin compiler is going to fail after each deprecated code usage. Unfortunately, Kotlin doesn’t support ignoring those is deprecated warnings or avoid failing on them.

The following Gradle script offers a solution to this issue.

```
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.internal.GradleInternal
import org.gradle.configurationcache.extensions.serviceOf
import org.gradle.internal.logging.events.operations.LogEventBuildOperationProgressDetails
import org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationDescriptor
import org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationListener
import org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationListenerManager
import org.gradle.internal.operations.OperationFinishEvent
import org.gradle.internal.operations.OperationIdentifier
import org.gradle.internal.operations.OperationProgressEvent
import org.gradle.internal.operations.OperationStartEvent

val kotlinWarnings = mutableListOf<String>()
val buildOperationListener = object : BuildOperationListener {
    override fun started(buildOperation: BuildOperationDescriptor, startEvent: OperationStartEvent) {
    }

    override fun progress(operationIdentifier: OperationIdentifier, progressEvent: OperationProgressEvent) {
        val log = progressEvent.details
        if (log is LogEventBuildOperationProgressDetails) {
            if (log.message.contains("w:") && !log.message.contains("is deprecated.") && !kotlinWarnings.contains(log.message)) {
                kotlinWarnings.add(log.message)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun finished(buildOperation: BuildOperationDescriptor, finishEvent: OperationFinishEvent) {
    }
}
val gradleInternal = project.gradle as GradleInternal
val buildOperationListenerManager = gradleInternal.serviceOf() as BuildOperationListenerManager?
buildOperationListenerManager?.addListener(buildOperationListener)
project.gradle.buildFinished {
    buildOperationListenerManager?.removeListener(buildOperationListener)
    if (kotlinWarnings.isNotEmpty()) {
        kotlinWarnings.forEach { project.logger.warn(it) }
        throw RuntimeException("Kotlin warning found")
    }
}
```

Basically, a `BuildOperationListener` is added to the Gradle build, so you can listen for each console log. Each log is inspected searching for Kotlin warnings, but ignoring the deprecated usage warnings. Finally, an exception is thrown if there are Kotlin warnings on the project

---

The following article gives more info about this topic: [Fail your build on Kotlin warnings](https://medium.com/dipien/fail-your-build-on-kotlin-warnings-96c4d9b3fd33)